# Windows Batch - separate directory and filename from full file path string

Tags: windows, batch-file, path, directory, filenames

I'd like to separate both a filename and a directory string from inside a full file path variable so i can refer to each separately later in a batch script.

Input Variable: SET "FULL=C:\test\file.txt"

Wanted Output:

FILE: file.txt

PATH: C:\test\

Currently the for loop & syntax is not making a whole lot of sense to me (in this batch scripting language) which is making it harder for me to find a working solution online...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
set "FULL=C:\test\file.txt"

for %%a in ("%FULL%") do (
    set "filePath=%%~dpa"
    set "file=%%~nxa"
)
```

`for` loop will iterate over a `set` of files (only one file in set in this case), and for each of them the code after the `do` clause is executed.

For each iteration of the `for` loop and so for each execution of the `do` clause, the replaceable parameter (the `%%a` in the previous code) will hold a reference to the file being processed.

This replaceable parameter has some modifiers (that can be seen running `for /?`) to retrieve the required information from the file. The modifiers are in the form

```
%% ~ modifier replaceableParameter
```

In the previous sample code, `d` modifier is the drive where the file is stored,  `p` is the path (folder hierarchy) where the file is stored, `n` is the file name without extension and `x` is the extension. So

```
%%~dpa = drive and path of the file being referenced by a
%%~nxa = name and extensions of the file being referenced by a
```

Comment: Very detailed! Thank you, now i understand this a lot better. And it works exactly how i need it in a script i'm writing.